# Kendo grid: How to remote filter above 2 values from one column

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, filtering

I have one column in kendo grid but if i'm filtering opposite the server API i need to filter against two values.

It means something like this:

```
{
    "entityName": "client",
    "data": {
        "take": 10,
        "skip": 0,
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "filter": {
            "logic": "and",
            // IN FILTER IS IMPORTANT TO HAVE 2 OBJECTS    
            "filters": [
                {
                    "operator": "eq",
                    "value": "test",
                    "field": "client.name"
                },
                {
                    "operator": "eq",
                    "value": "test",
                    "field": "client.surname"
                }
            ]
        },
        "group": []
    }
}
```

I tried it by this way:

```
filterable : {
                    cell :
                        [
                            {

                                dataTextField : "client.name",
                                operator : "contains"
                            },
                            {

                                dataTextField : "client.surname",
                                operator : "contains"
                            }
                        ]
                }
```

But without luck.

How can i do it please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Let me see if I'm following you: In one column filter you would like to filter both `name` and `surname`, right ?

Comment: Yes name and surname against the server api. To get filter request with two object (like in question), now it contains only one.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you'll have to intercept the dataSource data request and change the filter inside the readOptions before it get to the server.  You'll have to create a custom `transport.read` and each time the dataSource will request some data, it will pass the readOptions parameter to that function.

```
myGrid.kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
      read: function (readOptions) {
        readOptions.filter.filters = [{
            operator: "eq",
            value: "test",
            field: "client.name"
          }, {
            operator: "eq",
            value: "test",
            field: "client.surname"
          }];

        //Insert you logic to retrieve the data from the server
        //You may also try to call the dataSource original read function and pass the modified readOptions
        //The ajax is just an example...
        $.ajax({data: readOptions}).done(function(data){
          readOptions.success(data);
        });


      }
    }
}
```

Remember that if you overwrite the read function, you are responsible to call the readOptions success / error function to notify the dataSource about the data callback.